# Shouldnt the x[1] just take the second array in the multidimensional array=

Tags: python, function, sorting, lambda

I have trouble understanding the lambda function, I always confuse myself because I overthink everything, here my problem:

```
nm = input().split()
n = int(nm[0])
m = int(nm[1])
arr = []

for _ in range(n):
    arr.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

k = int(input())

arr.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

What the Code does isn't important right now, but I receive following output if I print my array(for my example):

```
[[7, 1, 0], [10, 2, 5], [6, 5, 9], [9, 9, 9], [1, 23, 12]]
```

As you can see it is a multidimensional array, now I want to sort it based on the second element of each list:

```
arr.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

So I have the list and I want to sort it with the key lambda and the variable x: x[1] shouldn't my variable x be the multidimensional array? Isnt it the same if I say x = arr,
how exactly does this function know i want to sort all the elements that are at position x[1] from each list, i would have thought using x[1] would only be the second array in the multidimensional array:

```
[[1, 2, 3], **[4, 2, 6]** ...
```

Im a beginner so I would appreciate a beginner friendly response to my question,
cheers!

Comment: "shouldn't my variable x be the multidimensional array" - no. That would make `key` completely unusable.

Comment: No, `x` is not `arr`, but each element in `arr`, like when using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain what this line does in plain language:

`arr.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])`

It basically says: take each element of arr, call it x, and then use x[1] as the sorting key.

So your input is this:

`[[7, 1, 0], [10, 2, 5], [6, 5, 9], [9, 9, 9], [1, 23, 12]]`

It is a list of lists, so if you use the sort function, the result is also a list of lists, ordered according to the key defined in the lambda function. Let's go through what the lambda does here:

- Set `x` to the first element of arr: `[7, 1, 0]`. `x[1]` is now 1
- Set `x` to the second element of arr:  `[10, 2, 5]`. `x[1]` is now 2.
- Set `x` to the third element of arr:  `[6, 5, 9]`. `x[1]` is now 5.
- Set `x` to the fourth element of arr:  `[9, 9, 9]`. `x[1]` is now 9.
- Set `x` to the fifth element of arr:  `[1, 23, 12]`. `x[1]` is now 23.

The keys we have extracted this way are now `[1, 2, 5, 9, 23]`. It is this list of numbers that determines the sorting order. Since the keys are already in order, sorting `arr` this way will not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

No, `x` in the `lambda` is not the entire `arr` (that would be kind of pointless), but each *element* in `arr`, like when using a `for` loop.

From the documentation of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) (it's the same for `list.sort`), my highlighting:

> `key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key **from each element in iterable** (for example, `key=str.lower`). The default value is `None` (compare the elements directly).

The function is applied to each element to extract or calculate the comparison key from that element. In your case, it takes the second element `[1]` from each `x` in `arr`, e.g. `x` is `[6, 5, 9]`, the key function extracts `5`, and thus it is sorted third.

The way I understand your question, this is exactly what you wanted to do. If instead you want to sort the second sublist of `arr`, you could do `arr[1].sort()`, or if you want just the second elements in sorted order, it would be e.g. `sorted(x[1] for x in arr)`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `lambda x: x[1]` is just convenient syntax for creating
function objects. So instead of

```
arr.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

you can write:

```
def key_fun(x):
    return x[1]
arr.sort(key=key_fun)
```

I recommend doing it that way until you learn more about Python.

`arr.sort` with the `key` argument is also a type of convenient
syntax. Instead of `arr.sort(key=key_fun)` you can write:

```
arr2 = [(key_fun(x), x) for x in arr]
arr2.sort()
arr = [x for (key, x) in arr2]
```

Under the hood, `arr.sort(key=key_fun)` does roughly the same job for
you.